# Eliminar valor en array en documento en mongodb

Tags: array, mongodb

Buenas a todos quisiera saber como puedo eliminar este valor Donoso Pedro de un array que esta bajo de otro, entiendo el tema de operadores posicionales sin embargo me sale como:
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 0 }

[image: Este es el documento]

Les dejo el codigo de la consulta:
[image: La consulta]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código de la pregunta debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Solo tienes un documento en la coleccion de estaciones?

Comment: No, tengo muchos. Me pidieron eliminar especificamente a esta persona independiente del documento que estaba. Pero lo solucione, gracias